# I want when i got 401 error code then application will logout. But in my case , logout api call but it is not logout properly

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

```
const store = configureStore();
let isLogout = false;
const handleResponse = (response) => {
  if (response && response.data && response.data.status && response.data.status.code === 401 && !isLogout ) {
    isLogout = true;
    store.getState().Login.isAuthenticated= false;
    store.dispatch(actions.logout());
  }
  return response
}

axiosApi.interceptors.response.use(
  response => handleResponse(response)
)
```

````
``` 
const initial_state = {
  userName: 'Name',
  isAuthenticated: localStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated') ? true : false
};

export default function loginReducers (state, action) {
  if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
    return initial_state;
  }
  const payload = action.payload || action;
  switch (action.type) {
    case loginConstants.LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
      return {
        initial_state,
        isAuthenticated: false
      };
    case loginConstants.SET_IS_AUTHENTICATED:
      return {
        isAuthenticated: payload.isAuthenticated
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```
````

I have mention my login action , login reducer also.

```
   const userObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authResponse'))
   const userId = 'abcd'
   const config = {};
   config.url = 'abc/logout?userId=' + userId;
   config.headers = {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   };
   dispatch(blockUI());

   ApiCall.getCall(config).then((response) => {
     if (response && response.status) {
       if ((response.status.code === 200 || response.status.code === 201)) {
         history.push('/login');
         localStorage.clear();
         dispatch({ type: LoginConstants.LOGOUT_SUCCESS });

       }
     }
     dispatch(unblockUI());
   });
 })
```

I have mention my login action , login reducer also.how to change redux state using store.getstate(). I want when i got 401 error code then application will logout. But in my case , logout api call but it is not logout properly

Comment: You can only update the state of the store within a reducer. Can your Login reducer not return updated state with `isAuthenticated: false` when it receives the logout action?

Comment: No ,Login reducer not return updated state. It return  isAuthenticated: true. But logout api call and localstorage clear.

Comment: Can you paste the login reducer? What I'm suggesting is that the reducer handling the state stored at `Login` in the store should update the value of `isAuthenticated` when it receives the `logout` action. Directly mutating the state of the store (e.g. `store.getState().Login.isAuthenticated = false;` will not work. You should only change the state of the store by returning an updated value from a reducer.

Comment: paste login reducer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In axios docs it has this info, so you need to handle second part for non 2xx errors, in your case 401.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

Assuming your 401 code in error.status.code:

```
axiosApi.interceptors.response.use(
    function(response) {
      return response;
    },
    function(error) {
       if (error.status.code === 401 ) {
        store.dispatch(actions.logout());
      }

      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
```

If you use token, in your logout action, you had better to remove it.

Comment: I got my response {"status":{"code":401,"message":"Fail"},"data":null}, not in error.response

Comment: @user3639569  then if statement mus tbe if (error.status.code === 401 )
I am editing answer

Comment: No i got, if( response && response.data && response.data.status && response.data.status.code === 401)

Comment: @user3639569  Ok when you used like that, did it worked?

Comment: In my code, logout api call but my page not redirect to login page

Comment: @user3639569 Ok then we solved to handle logout when 401. You have now another different problem. You may accept this answer, and ask a new question, or I can help to resolve new issue in here with a chat.

Comment: @user3639569 thank you, please ask your redirecting problem in a new question, so that others also can help. Give your new question's link here so that I don't miss it.